# Does Firefox's Reader View save PC resources?

Tags: firefox, performance

I have a series of articles from a media site that consume tons of resources. Complex templates, navigation, media inserts, bad JavaScript, yaddayaddayadda.

This causes big load on both CPU and memory.

If I load the page **directly** in Reader View (`about:reader?url=` prefix), without loading the page in Firefox tab first, will Firefox still incur performance penalty the non-reader page rendering incurs?

Or will all the superfluous resource consuming junk on the page never even attempt to get rendered?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Report back with your findings and [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: You could also try using tools like an ad blocker (tastes vary, but I'm a fan of Adblock Plus), NoScript, etc.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I strongly suspect the main resource leakage is NOT in the ads. Rich media and probably bad script would be my best guess. Having said that, my reason for asking this specific question is **more to specifically learn about Reader View** and less to arrive at a specific functional result no matter what the implementation (if all I cared about was resources, Feedly's reader mode is best).